# Should I connect solar panels in series or parallel for my charger?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charger

I am making a solar charger for 3 AA batteries. I have two 6 volt 100mah solar panels. Will it be more beneficial to connect them in parallel to have more current or in series to increase the voltage? The voltage of the 3 AAs will be at least 3.6 so I am wondering if there will be enough potential difference to charge them. I am aware that this charger will be slow and I will make sure that the batteries do not overcharge. They will probably be 1300mah 1.2 volt rechargeables. This is the solar panel: http://www.ebay.com/itm/301018398863?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: I recommend using a solar panel based charger, as they account for variation in light to the panels vs. the charge current and voltage needed. A direct connection can overcharge the batteries and standard charger IC's do not account for a wide range of voltage inputs such as a solar cell array.

Comment: I plan on watching over the charging process and making sure that the batteries do not overcharge. Many instructables do it this way. I hope it works

Answer (score 1):

(In this case) you're better off putting them in parallel - your batteries will not rise to 12V.

With the solar panels in series you will also have other issues.  Imagine that one of the panels does not receive sunlight - it would generate a low current and the other panel would generate a high current - I do not think that the low current panel will be happy with the high current of the other one.